# Is there way to create tables with case insensitive column values in oracle?

Tags: oracle10g

Is there a way to create tables  with case insensitive column values in Oracle?
I actually need to view Oracle through MS-Access ODBC and I need to make the tables case insensitive. Is there a way to alter session in MS Access like in oracle (below) to make the them case insensitive:

```
alter session set NLS_COMP=LINGUISTIC
alter session set NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI
```

Comment: You can use lower and upper oracle functions to make column values in a similar case. Also you can use "initcap" to make the first letter of the string to uppercase.

Comment: Thanks Raj for replying. But I am looking for some other way if possible, as the number of columns in tables are so large so cannot use UPPER and LOWER.